# Linear system. I know coefficients and solutions, I want to approximate inputs.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, least-squares, neural-networks

This may be a simple question, but I couldn't find a solution because I didn't know what to search for. Excuse my math.

I have a linear system $AX = Y$. $A$ is an affine transform and all the coefficients are known. $Y$ is the solution, and I know them. I need to find $X$. The reason I do this is because I need to find the magnitude of column vectors in $Y$ that corresponds to those in $X$. Dimensionality of these matrices are $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times 512}, X \in \mathbb{R}^ {512 \times k}, Y \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times k} $. $k$ is the number of column vectors, and $d$ is the dimensionality of output space. $A$ is not invertible.

Also, is there a way to solve this using least-squares? I don't think I can, but it was suggested that I use least-squares from someone.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks. Fixed notations.

Comment: Is $d$ less or greater than $512$?

Comment: "...because I need to find the magnitude of column vectors in $Y$... " what does that mean?  You have all of the matrix $Y$, so you can go ahead and compute the magnitudes of its columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to solve $Ax = y$ in terms of least squares (more precisely, $\arg\min_x \|Ax - y\|$), then you can write $x = A^+ y$, where $A^+$ is [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse). In your matrix case, you essentially have $k$ independent systems, and solution for them can be written in the same form simultaneously: $X = A^+ Y$